# Unix File move between 2 directory with relative path

Tags: linux

I am in the directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/me/Downloads`, there is a file titled `BigData.fasta.gz` present. I need to move this to the directory `/home/user/data` .

I have tried `cd ../../home/user/data` to no avail. I figured `cd` would change the directory and `../` would go back twice and the file would move to the `/home/user/data` directory. I am trying to accomplish this with a relative pathway.

Comment: Are you using wsl?

Answer (score 1):

- `.` means "current directory".
- `..` means "up one directory" or "parent directory"

These are the absolute vs relative paths for your case:

```
Relative                         Absolute
.                                /cygdrive/c/Users/me/Downloads
../                              /cygdrive/c/Users/me/
../../                           /cygdrive/c/Users/
../../../                        /cygdrive/c/
../../../../                     /cygdrive/
../../../../../                  /
../../../../../home/             /home/
../../../../../home/user/        /home/user/
../../../../../home/user/data/   /home/user/data/
```

If you are in `/cygdrive/c/Users/me/Downloads` and want to move `BigData.fasta.gz` to `/home/user/data` with relative paths, use:

```
mv BigData.fasta.gz ../../../../../home/user/data/
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, I would use the shorter absolute path for destination. Personally, I often use options `-vi` for this kind of `mv`:

- `-v` for verbose confirmation
- `-i` for interactive prompt before overwriting anything

Those switches have saved my bacon a few times.

Similarly, I like `-vip` switches for `cp` for similar reasons.